# Getting Master Detail to behave on UWP just like it does on Android and IOS

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.forms, uwp

I have a prism Xamarin Forms application which is being designed for both UWP, Android on IOS. This is the first UWP app that I have created. I want to have a menu that is only accessible from the first level of navigation. To do this, in the past, I have used a Master-Detail page. However, I have encountered some behaviour differences that I need some help with.

When I use a Master-Detail screen on IOS or Android it behaves like a menu only accessible to the first level of navigation. Any subpage that you might navigate from there you don't see menu it is replaced by the back button.

When I use a Master-Detail screen on UWP it's behaviour is different. The menu is available on all pages no matter how far into the navigation stack you travel. It is by default also a menu tray of items anchored on the left side of your application.

I have figured out how to make the menu collapse into the hamburger button that I am used to on an Android and IOS application by setting the parameter MasterBehavior to the value Popover. But I would like to have the menu completely disappear on any page navigated past the first level as it does on IOS of Android.

Does anyone know of a way to make this happen?

Comment: Could you please post a [mcve] to show what you have done?

Comment: I have updated the question hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I can say safely that this can't be done in pure Xamarin.Forms.

To change this you would have to change to which UWP Frame the content is loaded, and I am not aware that Frame is exposed anywhere in Xamarin.Forms which means that even custom renderers cannot help.

However you may try to build the native navigation that would act like that in the UWP project and then load inside those native controls Xamarin.Forms page, that should work and deliver the results that you have requested. Not trivial and no few lines that I can show you, but if that is important for you it should be possible this way.